# How to Catch error code from odooRPC response integrated with angular 4

Tags: angular, odoo

I have my Angular project integrated with odooRPC API ,In the JSON response which i receive from odooRPC is as given below :

```
 error:{message: "Odoo Session Expired", code: 100, data: {,…}}
 code:100
 data:{,…}
 arguments:["Session expired"]
 debug : "Traceback (most recent call last):↵  raise http.SessionExpiredException("Session expired")↵SessionExpiredException: Session expired↵"
 exception_type:"internal_error"
 message :"Session expired"
 name : "odoo.http.SessionExpiredException"
 message : "Odoo Session Expired"
 id :null
 jsonrpc :"2.0"
```

this is the response from OddoRPC call function from network tab in chrome when an exception or an error has occurred, but my concern is I am not able to get this entire response when I catch this error. All I get is the error inside the debug parameter. Is there any way to get the 'code' or 'message' value

Any help will be appreciated.

Code which i use to call odoodRPC function inside angular:

```
   return this.odooRPC.call('connect', 'getList',[],{}).catch((e: any) => {
         console.log(e);
        });
```

here getList is the function which I call from Odoo server, and when I console it inside the catch block all I get is the error message from the 'debug' parameter.

Comment: Please share your code in your question.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Can you share `odooRPC` as well?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using one of the Odoo jsonrpc libraries for angular, like for example this one https://github.com/agenterp/angular5-odoo-jsonrpc. 
This library's function `call` process the response before it sends you the error. See below an excerpt from the library's `odoorpc.service.ts`

```
    errorObj.title = error.message;
    errorObj.message = error.data.debug.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
    ...
    return Promise.reject(errorObj);
```

You could either adapt the library for your use case or just call the `odoo` API directly with Angular's `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code, you have tried to access field ('is_affiliation_available') with recordset. But it gets int value not recordset. So we need to convert it into recordset.

Comment: This is the error message returned by the odooRpc, not an exception inside my code. So in such case i need to retrieve the error code from the response , which i am not able to in my angular code. I have updated my question .

Comment: Sorry. as per your given information, I can not find it. It seems their is problem inside function/method that you try to fetch it.